# Failing a Windows Service with an exit code

Tags: vb.net, windows-services

I want my service to be able to be restarted remotely (by a TCP client which is not part of this question). I configured the service to restart on failure on the Recovery tab for my service. In my code I set the [ServiceBase.ExitCode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.serviceprocess.servicebase.exitcode?view=netframework-4.6.1) to a non-zero number, say 1. I did not use [Environment.Exit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.exit?view=netframework-4.6.1) to stop the service because it isn't necessary to terminate the process. When I test my service it stops correctly and the Windows System Log reports that my service has stopped with an error. It also names the error. But my service does not restart! When I instead use Environment.Exit(1) the Windows System Log reports that my service has stopped unexpectedly without naming the error. It then does restart the service as if it has failed (like it should).

My question is, why doesn't the service restart with just a non-zero exitcode? The service stops with an error but that isn't failing? Is Environment.Exit the only way to properly trigger a service restart on failure? I liked using the ExitCode better because the System Log is cleaner and more accurate that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you check the "Enable actions for stops with errors" checkbox on the Recovery tab?

[image]

From the [technical documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winsvc/ns-winsvc-service_failure_actions_flag), the service's exit code is only consulted if that option is checked.

Comment: I did not. Thank you for pointing this out. The link to the technical documentation is exactly what I needed to know.